# R: For Loop within a For Loop, rebuilding and exporting the output each round

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, nested-loops

So, I am new to R.

I am trying to make something that reads a patient ID from a list of patients listx, extracts the corresponding column (column name = name of patient) in matrix 1 (genomicmatrix), and then runs a row-by-row statistical analysis between that column from genomicmatrix and another matrix (mxy), both of which have the same number of rows.

THEN, it writes the results into a CSV file.

THEN, it moves on to the next patient in listx and repeats the procedure.

Again, I'm new at this so I hope i'm being clear. Here's what I have so far:

```
for(i in seq_along(mxy)){
  for (j in seq_along(listx)){
    indgene <- try(gex[,listx[j][listx[j] %in% names(gex)]])
  }
  zvalues[i] <- (indgene[i] - mean(mxy[i,])) / sd(mxy[i,])
  geneexptest <- data.frame(gex$sample, zvalues, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  write.table(geneexptest$gex.sample, paste(names(listx)[j], ".csv", sep = ","), 
          row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",", quote=F)
  zvalues = NULL
  indgene = NULL
  geneexptest = NULL
}
```

SO I know it's kind of a mess. And it doesn't work. It just builds up a bunch of NAs in zvalue endlessly. I want it to build one indgene vector, use it to fill zvalues for THAT patient ONLY, make a dataframe and write it as a csv, then delete ALL that stuff and continue with the NEXT patient.

One more thing - is there any way to make the name of the CSV file change for every run (like name it after the patient ID currently being looked at?), so that the final output is x number of CSV files, each corresponding to a patient in listx.

THANKS SO MUCH!!

`gex`:

```
     sample TCGA-F4-6703-01 TCGA-DM-A28E-01 TCGA-AY-6197-01 TCGA-A6-5657-01
[1,]    987      0.79790041       2.3517004       1.7580004       0.6067004
[2,]   7829     -1.13418473      -1.4130847      -2.3078847       0.2550153
[3,]  15097     -0.45561492      -0.4556149      -0.4556149      -0.4556149
[4,]  15056      0.03217751      -0.1146225       0.1363775      -0.3028225
[5,]  15058     -0.31903849      -1.2251385      -1.2339385      -0.8575385
[6,]  15072     -0.19546513      -0.4911651      -0.7853651      -1.2155651


listx <- c("TCGA-DM-A28E-01","TCGA-A6-5657-01")
```

`mxy`:

```
     TCGA-AD-6963-01 TCGA-AA-3663-11 TCGA-AD-6901-01 TCGA-A6-A567-01
[1,]       1.0513004       1.2421004       1.5119004       1.6991004
[2,]      -0.7592847       3.2265153      -0.8288847      -0.4752847
[3,]      -0.4556149      -0.4556149      -0.4556149      -0.4556149
[4,]      -0.3492225       0.1348775      -0.1155225      -0.3586225
[5,]      -1.7248385       0.0427615      -1.5324385      -0.3399385
[6,]      -0.8287651      -0.3504651      -0.5890651      -0.1925651
```

Comment: Well, the reason why it builds zvalues of NULL is probably the line you have 3. to last in your loop that says `zvalues = NULL`.

Comment: Also, it seems like you have a . in gex.sample. But I can't see gex.sample defined anywhere.
Removing [i] from zvalues, as well as the last three lines should also help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Given the information in your example I have put this together.

First, I just generated random numbers in place of yours (because I got lazy after copying `sample`).

Secondly, because you are going to be saving this to a .csv file I changed the structure of the `colnames`. You have `-` as a seperator in your patient identifier, however, `colnames` in R replace these with `.`.

If you just used this same identifier from `listx`, when creating the name for the .csv file you would end up with: TCGA.DM.A28E.01.csv. But how is your file system going to know if you want to save a .csv file, or another format called .A28E.01.csv.

This is why you have the `gsub` lines after each data.frame.

```
gex <- data.frame("sample" =  c(987,7829,15056,15058,15072), 
              "TCGA-F4-6703-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
              "TCGA-DM-A28E-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
              "TCGA-AY-6197-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
              "TCGA-A6-5657-01" = runif(5, -1, 1))
colnames(gex) <- gsub("[.]", "_",colnames(gex))

listx <- c("TCGA_DM_A28E_01","TCGA_A6_5657_01")

mxy <- data.frame("TCGA-AD-6963-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
              "TCGA-AA-3663-11" = runif(5, -1, 1),
              "TCGA-AD-6901-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
              "TCGA-A6-A567-01" = runif(5, -1, 1)) 

colnames(mxy) <- gsub("[.]", "_",colnames(mxy))

lapply(1:length(mxy), function(i){
  lapply(1:length(listx), function(j){
    indgene <- gex[listx[j]]

    zvalues <- (indgene[i] - mean(mxy[,i])) / sd(mxy[,i]) 
    geneexptest <- data.frame(gex$sample, zvalues, row.names = NULL, 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    write.csv(geneexptest, file = paste0(listx[j], ".csv"), 
          row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",", quote=F)
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi @kristang, thanks for the feedback. This helps a lot. However, I get the following error:Error in paste0(names(listx)[j]) : object 'j' not found

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code and changed the loops to lapply :). As you can see in my code, as well as your loop is actually closed after indgene is defined. You can try moving the closure }) down after write.csv and see if that helps. I can't really determine if it causes any trouble right off the bat.

Comment: I resolved the write.csv issue. I was using paste0 incorrectly. Apart from that, it seems that instead of defining indgene as the single column from gex to be processed (like corresponding to a single patient at a time), it just puts all of the patients into indgene at the same time, so there are x number of columns. Problem is, zvalues cannot be calculated if there is more than one column. Do you know how to afford only one column at a time into indgene? Thanks!

Comment: Well, like I said it can be a bit tricky when I don't know the precise structure of gex. Maybe using `colnames` instead of `names` in `select` will change it?

Comment: Now attached to the original post is a cutout of gex. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: I've also included some of 'mxy', as well as what 'listx' could potentially look like given the matrix cutouts. Desired output is one 'geneexptest' (as in your script) CSV file PER patient. That is, one for "TCGA-DM-A28E-01", and one for "TCGA-A6-5657-01"

Comment: Hi @kristang, it would be tremendously helpful if you had any idea of how to run this one column at a time as described in above comments! I would of course check off your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @kristang, thanks for your answer. One last issue! I received the following error: `Error in mean(mxy[, i]) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': Error in mxy[, i] : subscript out of bounds` - I guess it's because mxy and mxx could each have any number of columns (it changes based on which analysis I'm doing).

Comment: `subscript out of bounds` means `i` is increased beyond what is available in `mxy`. If `i` is 3, but there are only 2 columns in `mxy` it's going to throw that error.

Comment: would try() or tryCatch() remedy this?

Comment: Yeah, but you should really try to account for an error when you know the issue by correcting it.